# how can I dynamically schedule the tests to be run by TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

In a given suite which uses 10 threads and has 100 tests I want to provide tests to be run dynamically so that next to be run test case out of remaining tests need to determined by my own logic and given to TestNg when thread(s) completes current test/tests.

Simply put how can I **dynamically schedule** the tests to be run by TestNG?

**Adding more info below**

Let's say I have 100 tests to run with say 10 threads. typically tests will be picked up in random and executed. Here I need **control** on next test to be run when a thread finishes current test run.
In simple terms this will help us to lock and unlock the objects on product and schedule the tests such that more tests can run in parallel by sharing existing resources.

*Ultimately need to reorder the remaining tests every time want to run the next test & need a way to do it in testNg*

Answer (score 0):

@Factory lets you create test classes dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, Cedric, Can you please elaborate on this. I specify the test classes in XML and they already have @Test annotations. now I want to choose the test to be run by checking with test environment and give it to testNG. So how @Factory can be used here?

Comment: I'm not sure since your question was pretty vague. @Factory lets you create test classes dynamically. Based on your comment, maybe what you actually want to use is groups. Are you familiar with these?

Comment: Cedric, I need control on the next test to be run so that I can elect right test out of remaining tests which can run based on the resources availability on the product. I have edited the question and have elaborated the question, please have a look at it.

Comment: For this kind of control, you probably want to use dependencies then, this will guarantee that certain tests are only run once tests they depend on are run first.

Comment: But again we can't change the dependencies dynamically, its done at compile time :-( I need to change the next test to be run at run time. Is there any interface / class which I can extend or implement over testNG to go in my own way of executing parallel tests?

Comment: That's not really possible since TestNG needs to have an overall view of all your test methods before it can make decisions on which ones to run when. Adding or removing methods at runtime would create a pretty chaotic situation. Why can't you just put this behavior in your tests themselves?

Comment: By the way, I suggest you email testng-users with your scenario, we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thanks, will mail the group with more details.